# Inverter string em C

Tags: c, string

Estou a tentar inverter uma *string* em C mas a função está a limpá-la:

```
for(i = 0; i < (int)(size/2); i++)
{
   tmp = buffer[i]; //armazena o character inicial
   buffer[i] = buffer[size - i]; //Troca o character da ponta oposta
   buffer[size - i] = tmp; //Armazena o character inicial no buffer
}
```

Porque me limpa a string quando volto a fazer strlen dessa string?

A string Hello tem 5 caracteres, assim, a variável size terá o valor 5.~
alterando os valores no código acima:

- tmp = buffer[0] (o caracter 'H')
- buffer[i] = buffer[size - i] (a posição onde estava o caracter H terá agora o valor do caracter da posição [5 - 0], ou seja, a posição 5, que corresponde ao caracter 'o')
- buffer[size - i] = tmp (como tmp tinha o valor do caracter já armazenado em buffer[i], então, a posição do caracter 'o' terá o valor do caracter 'H')

Esta análise está correta? Qual o problema?

Comment: Feito. Mais uma vez obrigado

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O problema é que "size - i" vai pegar um caractere além do comprimento da string. Por exemplo, uma string com tamanho 5 (size=5) vai ter caracteres em s[0], s[1], s[2], s[3] e s[4], mas s[5] será o caractere \0. Assim que esse caractere é jogado em s[0], a string parecerá ter comprimento zero dali em diante, apesar de continuar ocupando seis posições de memória.

Na minha visão o programa deve ser corrigido para buffer[size - i - 1]. Acho que o (int) no size/2 também é desnecessário se size for de tipo inteiro, porque em C uma divisão de número inteiro sempre retorna um inteiro arredondado para baixo.

Comment: Não acredito, esqueci-me que a array começa no valor 0... eu pensei a começar no valor 0 e contei a começar no valor 1.

Answer (score 5):

O maior problema é que está esquecendo de retirar 1 na posição final.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char buffer[] = "Hello";
    size_t size = strlen(buffer);
    for(int i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {
       char tmp = buffer[i]; //armazena o character inicial
       buffer[i] = buffer[size - i - 1]; //Troca o character da ponta oposta
       buffer[size - i - 1] = tmp; //Armazena o character inicial no buffer
    }
    printf("%s", buffer);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Sano52). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/zejtcuph-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Invert2.c).

Comment: Sim, tal como já disse, eu pensei na array a começar pelo valor 0 e contei os caracteres a começar pelo valor 1. Estupidez minha. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Segue solução (testada) para o problema proposto:

```
/* reverse.c */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * reverse( char * s )
{
    int length = strlen(s) ;
    int c, i, j;

    for (i = 0, j = length - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
    {
        c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[j];
        s[j] = c;
    }

    return s;
}


int main( void )
{
    char str[] = "Ola Mundo!";

    printf("%s\n", reverse(str) );

    return 0;
}

/* fim-de-arquivo */
```

Answer (score 0):

mano seria melhor assim.Ignora esse 255.

```
   char nome[255];
   int tam;
   scanf("%254[^\n]", nome);
   tam=strlen(nome);
    for(i=tam-1;i>=0;i--){

 printf("%c",nome[i]);

    }
```